# Sorting by user upvotes and downvotes not working properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I currently have a model as such

```
class IpAddress(models.Model):
    creado = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ip_address = models.GenericIPAddressField(unique=True)

class Palabra(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    definicion = models.CharField(max_length=1000, unique=True)
    ejemplo = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    creado = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    anonimo = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    aprobada = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    userUpVotes = models.ManyToManyField(IpAddress, blank=True, related_name='threadUpVotes')
    userDownVotes = models.ManyToManyField(IpAddress, blank=True, related_name='threadDownVotes')
    gramatica = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    pais = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
```

And my ranking functions is as such

```
        defeniciones = Palabra.objects.prefetch_related(
            'tag_set'
        ).filter(
            nombre__iexact=palabra,
            aprobada=True
        ).annotate(
            total_votes=Count('userUpVotes') / NullIf((Count('userUpVotes') + Count('userDownVotes')), 0)).order_by('-total_votes')
```

I have a situation where a word has two upvotes and no downvotes.  But a word with no upvotes or downvotes, ranks higher.

I'm using `NullIf` due to postgres.

And an example is [here](https://diccionarioespa%C3%B1ol.com/significado/pedo/) where it ranks one with 1 upvote over one with 6 upvotes.

Full view

```
class PalabraView(View):
    def get(self, request, palabra=None):
        defeniciones = Palabra.objects.prefetch_related(
            'tag_set'
        ).filter(
            nombre__iexact=palabra,
            aprobada=True
        ).annotate(total_upvotes=Count('userUpVotes'),
                   total_votes=Count('userUpVotes') / NullIf((Count('userUpVotes') + Count('userDownVotes')),
                                                             0)).order_by(F('total_votes').desc(nulls_last=True),
                                                                          "-total_upvotes")
        for post in defeniciones:
            post.up_votes = post.userUpVotes.all()
            post.down_votes = post.userDownVotes.all()
            tags = post.tag_set.all()
            post.sins = ', '.join(['<a href="/significado/%s/">%s</a>' % (
                str(item).lower().strip('.'),
                str(item).lower().strip('.'),
            ) for item in tags.filter(tag_type='Sinónimo')])
            post.ants = ', '.join(['<a href="/significado/%s/">%s</a>' % (
                str(item).lower().strip('.'),
                str(item).lower().strip('.'),
            ) for item in tags.filter(tag_type='Antónimo')])

        paginator = Paginator(defeniciones, 20)  # Show 25 contacts per page.
        page_number = request.GET.get('page')
        page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
        add_word = False
        ipaddress = IpAddress.get_my_ip(request)
        if defeniciones.count() == 0:
            add_word = True
        context = {
            'add_word': add_word,
            'palabra': palabra,
            'defeniciones': defeniciones,
            'title': '%s: Significado de %s - DiccionarioEspañol.com' % (palabra.capitalize(), palabra),
            'description': '%s: Significado de %s en DiccionarioEspañol.com' % (palabra.capitalize(), palabra),
            'page_obj': page_obj,
            'ipaddress': ipaddress,
            'countries': COUNTRIES
        }

        return render(request, 'palabra.html', context)
```

Comment: Your problem is probably in your total_votes count, I suggest you should make total_votes = userUpVotes - userDownVotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`total_votes` for word with 0 upvotes and 0 downvotes equals `NULL`. You can check it this way:

```sql
SELECT 0 / NULL;
---
<null>
```

Also `NULL` ranks higher than everything when you're sorting `DESC`, for example:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (VALUES (NULL), (1), (NULL)) "n" ORDER BY "n" DESC;
---
<null>
<null>
1
```

So you just need to add [NULLS LAST](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/expressions/) and everything would work fine:

```py
from django.db.models import F  

...

defeniciones = Palabra.objects.prefetch_related(
    'tag_set'
).filter(
    nombre__iexact=palabra,
    aprobada=True
).annotate(
    total_votes=Count('userUpVotes') /
                NullIf((Count('userUpVotes') + Count('userDownVotes')), 0)
).order_by(F('total_votes').desc(nulls_last=True))
```

Comment: I added this, and it still ranks the one with least upvotes above the one with more upvotes.

Comment: I thought your problem was between "2 / 0" and "0 / 0" users. Formula you use sorts posts on percentage of upvotes in all votes. If you also need to put posts with more upvotes higher, you can add second sorting parameter, like this: `.annotate( 
    total_upvotes=Count('userUpVotes'),
    total_votes=Count('userUpVotes') /
                NullIf((Count('userUpVotes') + Count('userDownVotes')), 0)
).order_by(F('total_votes').desc(nulls_last=True), "-total_upvotes")`

Comment: I awarded the bounty, as it half works.  If you still check the link I give in the example.  It now does rank the 6, 1, correctly, but it ranks the 4/2 below the 3/4.

Comment: Could you attach the full code of that view? I believe something else is wrong here.

Comment: I have added it

Comment: I'm really confused. Maybe you could retrieve the actual `total_votes` values of those two posts? We might have a lead.

Comment: Got it working by changing `total_upvotes` to  `total_upvotes=Count('userUpVotes')-Count('userDownVotes'),`